# Passing larger akka messages within the same jvm

Tags: scala, akka

When passing messages from within the same JVM, are the messages still going through a serialization process?

If the message is large, how much more overheard is there?

Answer (score 1):

No, local messages between actors in Akka are not serialized (this is why they need to be immutable). Consequentially, there is no overhead sending large messages compared to small messages.